# magento2 Lillik price Decmial

Tags: magento2

I setup this extension in my project it work fine on forntend but its also remove price decimal from admin when i change the price this show the diffretent value may be format issue plz guide extension not effect in admin

Comment: could you update you question with its di.xml file ? ( would be in etc folder )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bug in this extension you would need to disable a preference which is overriding the currency model :

comment this line of code in etc/di.xml file of the extension :

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\CurrencyInterface" type="Lillik\PriceDecimal\Model\Currency" />
```

your di will be something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

<preference for="Lillik\PriceDecimal\Model\ConfigInterface" type="Lillik\PriceDecimal\Model\Config" />
<!--<preference for="Magento\Framework\Locale\CurrencyInterface" type="Magento\Framework\Locale\Currency" />-->

<!-- Comment out this preference for invalid price update i.e 12,344 to 12.344 ( replaces , with . ) -->
<!-- preference for="Magento\Framework\CurrencyInterface" type="Lillik\PriceDecimal\Model\Currency" / -->

<type name="Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface">
    <plugin name="lillik_price_decimal_price_currency"
            type="Lillik\PriceDecimal\Model\Plugin\PriceCurrency"
            sortOrder="10"
            disabled="false"/>
</type>

<type name="Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface">
    <plugin name="lillik_price_decimal_local_format"
            type="Lillik\PriceDecimal\Model\Plugin\Local\Format"
            sortOrder="10"
            disabled="false"/>
</type>
```